# Technical reasons that C++11 can't support templated typedefs

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In C++03, you couldn't template aliases, but since C++11 it's allowed with the `using` syntax.

For example, the following (using `typedef`) is invalid:

```
template<class T>
typedef vector<T> v;
```

Whereas the following (using `using`) is fine:

```
template<class T>
using v = vector<T>;
```

My question is not related to the rationale of The Committee for only supporting templated aliases with `using`.

My question is, is there any *technical* reason that this couldn't be supported? Basically, were the committee to allow this with `typedef`, would there be any implementation problems? For example, would it conflict with something else or cause some weird parsing issue?

For any cases I've been able to come up with, it should be fine, but I'm no expert which is why I'm asking here.

Research I've done, that doesn't answer the question:

- [Why do type aliases in C++ use 'using' instead of 'typedef' in their syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916435/why-do-type-aliases-in-c-use-using-instead-of-typedef-in-their-syntax/24916837#24916837) discusses the Committee's rationale, but not any technical reasons.
- [C++ template typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795023/c-template-typedef) discusses not being able to use templated `typedef`, not any technical reasoning behind it.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason why this couldn't be done. My understanding is that `typedef` has been effectively replaced by `using` and it doesn't make sense to backport features to language constructs that have been supplanted -- it adds complexity to the language for no benefit.

Comment: @cdhowie that is the impression I've gotten as well, but haven't been able to find a proper source to back it up, hence this question...